# Show that linear combination of ridge functions is dense in $C([0,1]^{d})$

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, vector-spaces

Let $\mathcal{R}(\mathbf{a}^{1},...,\mathbf{a}^{k})$ be a linear combination of ridge functions, in particular,

\begin{align}
\mathcal{R}(\mathbf{a}^{1},...,\mathbf{a}^{k}) = \bigg\{\sum_{i=1}^{k}g_i(\mathbf{a}^{i}\cdot\mathbf{x}): g_i \in C([0,1]), i=1,...,k\bigg\}.
\end{align}

Now I would like to show/prove that the following statement holds.

**Statement:** $\mathcal{R}(\mathbf{a}^{1},...,\mathbf{a}^{k})$ is dense in $C([0,1]^{d})$.

Here I am considering the uniform norm on my vector space. On page 179 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.14125.pdf, V.E. Ismailov states a Theorem, Theorem 5.1, that basically states that the above statement is true as long as $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}\tau^{n}([0,1]^d) = \emptyset$. Now V.E. Ismailov does not really go into detail on these set functions $\tau^{n}$ (construction is given) but I think it expresses the condition that there should be no cycles in $[0,1]^d$. However, I have no idea what `having no cycles' for such a compact set, $[0,1]^{d}$, even means.

This whole branch of mathematics is not my strong suit. Please correct me for any mistake and reach out if anything is unclear.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: have you tried using Stone-Weierstrass?

Comment: @MatíasUres Thanks for commenting. Yes, I know one can go the Stone-Weierstrass route. However, I am specifically interested in the 'ridge function' route, since it seems more elegant.